# IE8 padding-bottom not appearing on scrollable div

Tags: html, internet-explorer-8, padding

I have been looking for a solution to an IE8 issue regarding padding on a div with overflow: auto. When the content is scrollable IE8 doesn't seem to honour the bottom padding. An example of the issue can be seen here http://jsfiddle.net/Gbp5U/ (issue only appears in IE8)

In IE8 when the content is scrolled to the bottom there is a bottom-padding of what appears to be 0px. All other browsers, that I have tested, show the bottom padding. The developer tool in IE8 reports the bottom-padding as 20px but to me that is clearly not the case.

Has anyone else come across this issue and found a solution. The only workaround I have for the moment is to force IE8 to compatibility mode which I would rather not do.

Answer (score 0):

A suggested solution elsewhere was to place the div content within its own div with the appropriate padding as seen here: http://jsfiddle.net/Gbp5U/19/

I'm not a fan of it but I guess it works......